# How to Access Set-Cookie Values with httpUrlConnection.getHeaderFields() When Headers Are Empty Due to HTTP Only Cookie Restrictions?

Tags: java-8, httpurlconnection, setcookie, cookiestore, cookiemanager

I'm facing a challenge in accessing HTTP Only cookies in a large-scale Java application that uses httpUrlConnection. When trying to extract cookies from the Set-Cookie header of the HTTP response, I often encounter empty headers, which I suspect is due to the security restrictions of HTTP Only cookies.

Here is a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL).getCookieStore();
Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = httpUrlConnection.getHeaderFields();
```

When I call httpUrlConnection.getHeaderFields() to obtain Set-Cookie, the headers often come back empty. I need a way to access these values without having to refactor the entire application to a different library like Apache HttpClient, due to the significant impact that would have.

**My considerations are:**

- I understand that HTTP Only cookies are a security measure and should not be accessible by client-side scripts, but how can I properly manage them on the server side with Java?
- Is there any configuration in httpUrlConnection or another approach that can be used to work around this issue?
- Any guidance or suggestions on how to handle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: None of this has anything to do with "httpOnly" cookie, which just prevents browser scripts, not server scripts. When the list is empty, the server doesn't send any new cookies. The server doesn't send them over and over again, that's why you have the cookie store...